# How to display username after login using node.js, connect-flash, because i keep getting the error 'req is not defined'

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, require

I want to display the username on the main page after a successful login, using connect-flash but I am getting the error 'req is not defined' at 'app.post (req.flash("user", req.body.username))'.
I got the same error at 'app.get' but I moved 'app.use(flash )' above and it disappeared.
Please try to explain like to 5 year old.

HTML Code

```
<p>Hello <%= username %></p>
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="username">
          <!-- font awesome icon -->
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
        <label for="password">
          <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          id="password"
          required
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

JS Code

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const flash = require("connect-flash");

const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "nodelogin",
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// http://localhost:3000/
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  // Render login template
  const username = request.flash("user");
  response.render("login", { username });
});

// http://localhost:3000/auth
app.post("/", function (request, response) {
  // Capture the input fields

  let username = request.body.username;
  let password = request.body.password;

  // Ensure the input fields exists and are not empty
  if (username && password) {
    // Execute SQL query that'll select the account from the database based on the specified username and password
    connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",
      [username, password],
      function (error, results, fields) {
        // If there is an issue with the query, output the error
        if (error) throw error;
        // If the account exists
        if (results.length > 0) {
          // Authenticate the user
          request.session.loggedin = true;
          request.session.username = username;
          // Redirect to home page
          req.flash("user", req.body.username);
          response.redirect("/");

          console.log("succes");
        } else {
          response.send("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
        }
        response.end();
      }
    );
  } else {
    response.send("Please enter Username and Password!");
    response.end();
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like it is not able to find req object, could you try once replacing your req by request

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to always use the `Answer` field for answers! You can keep conversations on the comments field! [StackOverflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)